# Integral of the product of the binomial and logit-normal distributions

Tags: binomial-distribution, logit-normal-distribution

My problem is I have a specific [logit-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution) (I have $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$)  and I want to find the probability that if I were to sample the distribution, then use that value to perform $n$ trials I would get $k$ successes. It should be easier to understand with the equation:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}
\color{red}{\binom{n}{k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}}
\color{blue}{
\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\, 
e^{-\frac{(\ln(\frac{x}{1-x}) - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\frac{1}{x (1-x)}
}
dx
$$
Here the red part is the binomial distribution, and the blue part is the logit-normal distribution. In essence, I just want to find the integral of those two multiplied together between 0 and 1. I've done some work trying to make progress, but I've hit a dead end. I'll show you the basic process I've gone through. First I'll rearrange a bit
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\
\int_{0}^{1}
x^{k-1} (1-x)^{n-k-1} 
e^{-\frac{(\ln(\frac{x}{1-x}) - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
dx
$$
Then I can do a change of variable from $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$ to get rid of the logit from the exponent

$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{\exp(-x)}{(1+\exp(-x))^2}
\left(\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}\right)^{k-1}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}\right)^{n-k-1} 
e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
dx
$$
Simplifying, I can get the equation
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
e^{kx-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\frac{1}{(1+\exp(x))^n}
dx
$$
And at this point I'm stuck. Although I have a feeling that I've made progress, I still have no clue how to solve this integral. I've looked for an integral of this form in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, but I couldn't find anything (a few near misses, but still not anything notable enough for me to mention here. It's definitely possible I just missed something though).

PS a fast/efficient way to estimate this (or rather the logarithm of this) would also be useful. I have a decent one, but the formula has like 100 terms so it's not fast enough to be worth the downgrade in accuracy

Comment: I think numerical evaluation via adaptive Gauss-Hermite quadrature should work well, see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2337136

Comment: You can expand it into a series by breaking the integral into positive and negative parts (omitting a tiny interval around the origin), expanding $(1 + \exp(x))^{-n}$ directly using the Binomial Theorem for $x \lt 0$ and in the form $\exp(nx)(1+\exp(-x))^{-n}$ for $x \gt 0,$ and integrating the pieces.